# Same variable name and method TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, datatables

I would like to create a definition file for DataTables 1.9.4, but I have no idea how to deal with following [API](http://www.datatables.net/reference/api/). There is a method with the same name as variable. eg:

```
state();
state.clear();
state.loaded();
```

I would do it like this:

```
interface API {
    //...
    state(): any;
    state: StateInterface;
    //...
}
interface StateInterface {
    clear(): API;
    loaded(): any;
}
```

But this brings "Duplicate identifier" error...

Btw. The definition already exists, but for old API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple really :

```
interface State{
    ():any;
    clear:()=>any;
    loaded:()=>any;
}
declare var state:State;

state();
state.clear();
state.loaded();
```

Comment: Cool, method without name makes the thing. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a merged module to declare this, here is an ambient version:

```
declare function state(): void;
declare module state {
    export function clear(): void;
    export function loaded(): void;
}
```

This allows you to call all these methods:

```
state();
state.clear();
state.loaded();
```

If you are looking for a concrete version (not an ambient declaration) here is an example:

```
function state(): void {
    console.log('state');
}

module state {
    export function clear(): void {
        console.log('clear');
    }

    export function loaded(): void {
        console.log('loaded');
    }
}
```